# prevent duplicate form submission not working for table form

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf table form that is able to save data in the database as expected. Now the problem is I can't prevent duplicate form submission. I have tried all that I can but not been able to get it to work. Below is the code sample

entity class

```
public class TimeTable extends IdBaseEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy.GeneratedType.IDENTITY)
Integer id;

@Enumerated
WeekDays day;

@Column(name="start_time")
LocalTime startTime;

@Column(name = "end_time")
LocalTime endTime;

@Column(name = "room_number", length = 64)
String roomNumber;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "subject_id")
Subject subject;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "lectureroom_id")
LectureRoom lectureroom;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "section_id")
Section section;    
//constructors, getters and setter omitted
```

}

class for table form

```
public class TimeTableForm {
private Integer id;
private List<TimeTable> rows;
private Section sections;
private LectureRoom lectureroom;
private Subject subjects;
//setter and getter omitted
```

}

rest controller method

```
@PostMapping("/timetable/check-duplicates")
public String checkDuplicateTimeTable(TimeTableForm timeTable) {
    return timeTableService.isTimeTableUnique(timeTable) ? "Duplicated" : "OK";
}
```

controller method

```
@PostMapping("/timetable/save")
public String saveTimetable(@ModelAttribute("timetableForm") TimeTableForm timetableForm) {
     timeTableService.saveTimetable(timetableForm);
    return "redirect:/timetable";
}
```

service class method that check for duplicated data

```
public boolean isTimeTableUnique(TimeTableForm timeTableForm) {
List<TimeTable> rows = timeTableForm.getRows();
Section section = timeTableForm.getSections();
LectureRoom lectureRoom = timeTableForm.getLectureroom();
Subject subject = timeTableForm.getSubjects();

for (TimeTable row : rows) {
    TimeTable rowLisTable = timeTableRepo.findBySubjectAndSectionAndLectureRoomAndDayAndStartTimeAndEndTimeAndRoomNumber(
            subject, section,lectureRoom,row.getDay(),row.getStartTime(),row.getEndTime(),row.getRoomNumber());
    if (rowLisTable != null ) {
        return false; // Data already exists, not unique
    }
}

return true; // Data is unique
```

}

repository method

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM TimeTable t WHERE t.subject = :subject AND t.section = :section AND "
    + "t.lectureroom = :lectureroom AND t.day = :day AND t.startTime = :startTime AND "
    + "t.endTime = :endTime AND t.roomNumber = :roomNumber")
public TimeTable findBySubjectAndSectionAndLectureRoomAndDayAndStartTimeAndEndTimeAndRoomNumber(
                                               @Param("subject") Subject subject,
                                               @Param("section") Section section,
                                               @Param("lectureroom") LectureRoom lectureRoom,
                                               @Param("day") WeekDays day,
                                               @Param("startTime") LocalTime startTime,
                                               @Param("endTime") LocalTime endTime,
                                               @Param("roomNumber") String roomNumber);
```

table form with a onsubmit= "return checkTimetable(this);" which will trigger the rest controller to check for duplicate data before form submission

```html
<div >
            <form th:action="@{/timetable/save}" method="post" th:object="${timetableForm}"
            onsubmit= "return checkTimetable(this);">
                <div class="card card-body shadow mb-3 searchForm">
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                
                <div class="row ms-auto">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="coursecode">Class</label> 
                            <select class="form-select" th:field="*{lectureroom}" id="lectureroomId">
                                <th:block  th:each="lec : ${listLectureRooms}">
                                    <option th:value="${lec.id}">[[${lec.name}]]</option>
                                </th:block>
                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="coursecode">Section</label> 
                            <select class="form-select" th:field="*{sections}" id="sectionId">
                                <th:block  th:each="section : ${listSections}">
                                    <option th:value="${section.id}">[[${section.name}]]</option>
                                </th:block>
                                    
                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="coursecode">Subject</label> 
                            <select class="form-select" th:field="*{subjects}" id="subjectId">
                                <th:block  th:each="subject : ${listSubjects}">
                                    <option th:value="${subject .id}">[[${subject .name}]]</option>
                                </th:block>
                                    
                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
                
                <div class="card card-body">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive-sm align-middle" id="tableRefresh">
                    <thead class=" text-center">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Day</th>
                            <th scope="col">Start Time</th>
                            <th scope="col">End Time</th>
                            <th scope="col">Room Number</th>
                            
                            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="row, rowStat : ${rows}" >

                                <td>
                                [[${row.day}]]
                                    <input type="hidden"  th:field="*{rows[__${rowStat.index}__].day}"  id="'dayInput' + ${rowStat.index}">
                                </td>
                                
                                <td>
                                    <input type="time"  th:field="*{rows[__${rowStat.index}__].startTime}" class="form-control"  th:value="${startTime != null ? startTime : 'Not Scheduled'}">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="time"  th:field="*{rows[__${rowStat.index}__].endTime}" class="form-control" th:value="${endTime != null ? endTime : 'Not Scheduled'}">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text"  th:field="*{rows[__${rowStat.index}__].roomNumber}" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter room number">
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="d-grid justify-content-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-outline-success ">Save</button>                   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    
        function checkTimetable(form) {
            url = "[[@{/timetable/check-duplicates}]]"; 
            
        // Get the form data
        var subject = $("#subject").val();
        var section = $("#section").val();
        var lectureRoom = $("#lectureroom").val();
       
        var rowsData = [];

        // Loop through each row in the table body
        $("table tbody tr").each(function() {
            var day = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();
            var startTime = $(this).find("input[type='time']").eq(0).val();
            var endTime = $(this).find("input[type='time']").eq(1).val();
            var roomNumber = $(this).find("input[type='text']").val();

            // Create an object to store row data
            var rowData = {
                day: day,
                startTime: startTime,
                endTime: endTime,
                roomNumber: roomNumber
            };

            // Add row data object to the array
            rowsData.push(rowData);
        });

        // Create the params object with all the data
        var params = {
            id: timetableId,
            subject: timetableSubject,
            section:section,
            lectureroom: lectureRoom,
            rows: rowsData
        };
        
        alert(url);
        console.log(params);
        $.post(url, params, function(response){
            if(response == "OK"){
                form.submit();
            }else if(response == "Duplicate"){
              
              alert(startTime + " and " + endTime + "has already been set for " + subject + " on " + day);
            }else{
                
                alert("Unknown response from server");
            }
        }).fail(function(){
            alert("Could not connect to the server");
        });

        
        // Prevent the form from being submitted immediately
        return false;
    }
        </script>
```